# how to rearrange a column's elements in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column with values 1,2,4,7 how I can make it 1 to 4? that is:

```
 1==1  2==2   4==3   7==4


        col
         1
         2
         7
         1
         4
         7
```

output

```
        col
         1
         2
         4
         1
         3
         4
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to factor and then numeric:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 7, 1, 4, 7)
as.numeric(factor(x))
## [1] 1 2 4 1 3 4
```

Comment: Couly you please explain how this works? What would the difference be if one used `as.numeric(as.character....)` for instance?

Comment: Factors are internally represented by numbers and the default assignment is exactly the one in the question so after converting to factor just extract the internal representation using `as.numeric`. Using  `as.character` would not work.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't work